# Swipe tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tools, swipe

Is there any SWIPE tool in QGIS similar to what you have in ArcGIS.. What I am looking for is a tool to swap fast between two layers. I am comparing sidescan sonar mosaic against bathymetry for positioning issues.

Comment: would transparency not be the better way to compare the two? MBES and SSS have a good contrast.

Comment: Yes you are right, I use the transparency for that also. But as a nice and quick way of switching between the layers it would be nice with the swipe tool. Does it exist in QGIS?

Comment: I think that there is a plugin named "Dockable Mirror Map" (http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DockableMirrorMap/). It's not swipe but you can have synchronized canvas (I haven't use it).

Comment: Cheers, I will have a look at it :)

Answer (score 16):

[MapSwipe Tool](https://github.com/lmotta/mapswipetool_plugin) perhaps?

Its description:

> This plugin is a map tool for swipe active layer, for example, you can see the difference with others layers below.

Comment: Search no more. This is it.

Comment: How did you install this in QGIS?  At 2.12.0 I don't see MapSwipe in the plugin manager.  When I go to the link posted above, the latest listing (October 16) notes that it has been deactivated.  Huh?

Comment: It's an *experimental* plugin.  Do you have Plugin Manager set to *Show experimental plugins*?

Comment: @Tele-Pet, thanks, I have now set to show experimental plugins, and have installed the Swipe tool.

Comment: @Tele-Pet After briefly using this tool, I have an observation.  I expected the selected layer to disappear as I swiped (as in Arcmap).  However, with this tool, the selected layer is the only one that remains as you swipe; all other layers disappear.   To achieve the reverse (i.e. the Arcmap approach), group the layers that you want to remain visible, and then select that group to be swiped.  Thus the group remains, and the non-grouped layer(s) disappear.

Comment: @Tele-Pet: Thank you very much! Morten: Please mark this answer as correct answer/solution.